# Is there a way to extract the highlighted text from a table in docx document python?

Tags: python-3.x

[Image of the table i need to extract the highlighted text from.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txRI9.jpg)

I need to write a python script which helps me convert this docx table to csv and just writing the highlighted information from a row in a csv.
Like the column name would be "overall verdict" so its value underneath it must be "4".
Please if anyone can help, It would be appericiated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting Highlighted Words from Word Document (.docx) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562671/extracting-highlighted-words-from-word-document-docx-in-python)

Comment: but document.xpath function doesn't work.......error document has no attribute named xpath.

Comment: What docx version are you using? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376105/search-and-replace-in-python-docx You can search in your docx installation to verify that xpath doesn't exist.

Comment: yeah so that post says that xpath is no longer available in docx module.... so how i am gonna do the highlighted text extraction??

Comment: Don't know. You can download the older version. Or you could use a generic xml parser to read the unzipped docx, the format is in the linked question. Or you could write a basic search yourself...